# I am unable to make requests from python to a browser

Tags: python, github, python-requests, connection-timeout

i am trying to make requests to a server using requests lib from python but the code does not work and it gives me a Time Out Error every time i run the code Here is the code:

```
import requests

# Define the URL of the raw text file on GitHub
github_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebasics/nlp-tutorials/main/7_pos/news_story.txt"

# Send an HTTP GET request to fetch the content
response = requests.get(github_url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Print the content of the text file
    print(response.text)
else:
    print("Failed to fetch the content. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

and this is the error i get

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:174, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    173 try:
--> 174     conn = connection.create_connection(
    175         (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    176     )
    178 except SocketTimeout:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py:95, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     94 if err is not None:
---> 95     raise err
     97 raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py:85, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     84     sock.bind(source_address)
---> 85 sock.connect(sa)
     86 return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectTimeoutError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:714, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    713 # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 714 httplib_response = self._make_request(
    715     conn,
    716     method,
    717     url,
    718     timeout=timeout_obj,
    719     body=body,
    720     headers=headers,
    721     chunked=chunked,
    722 )
    724 # If we're going to release the connection in ``finally:``, then
    725 # the response doesn't need to know about the connection. Otherwise
    726 # it will also try to release it and we'll have a double-release
    727 # mess.

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:403, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    402 try:
--> 403     self._validate_conn(conn)
    404 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
    405     # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1053, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1052 if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1053     conn.connect()
   1055 if not conn.is_verified:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:363, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    361 def connect(self):
    362     # Add certificate verification
--> 363     self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
    364     hostname = self.host

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:179, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    178 except SocketTimeout:
--> 179     raise ConnectTimeoutError(
    180         self,
    181         "Connection to %s timed out. (connect timeout=%s)"
    182         % (self.host, self.timeout),
    183     )
    185 except SocketError as e:

ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021F9EBEB400>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:486, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    485 try:
--> 486     resp = conn.urlopen(
    487         method=request.method,
    488         url=url,
    489         body=request.body,
    490         headers=request.headers,
    491         redirect=False,
    492         assert_same_host=False,
    493         preload_content=False,
    494         decode_content=False,
    495         retries=self.max_retries,
    496         timeout=timeout,
    497         chunked=chunked,
    498     )
    500 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:798, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    796     e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", e)
--> 798 retries = retries.increment(
    799     method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    800 )
    801 retries.sleep()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py:592, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    591 if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 592     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    594 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /codebasics/nlp-tutorials/main/7_pos/news_story.txt (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021F9EBEB400>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectTimeout                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 7
      4 github_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebasics/nlp-tutorials/main/7_pos/news_story.txt"
      6 # Send an HTTP GET request to fetch the content
----> 7 response = requests.get(github_url)
      9 # Check if the request was successful
     10 if response.status_code == 200:
     11     # Print the content of the text file

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py:73, in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     62 def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
     63     r"""Sends a GET request.
     64 
     65     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
     70     :rtype: requests.Response
     71     """
---> 73     return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py:59, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     55 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     56 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     57 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     "timeout": timeout,
    586     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:507, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    504 if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
    505     # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
    506     if not isinstance(e.reason, NewConnectionError):
--> 507         raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
    509 if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):
    510     raise RetryError(e, request=request)

ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /codebasics/nlp-tutorials/main/7_pos/news_story.txt (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021F9EBEB400>, 'Connection to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

of course i can manually download this file as well but i want to solve this issue so please help me in this

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible.